# SQLServerDialect Override to register nvarchar type in Spring Boot

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am facing an issue with **nvarchar** type of SQL server and need to register it in Spring Boot Application.Since I am calling the existing stored procedure, I do not have an option to cast in query. Kindly suggest me if any other way to deal with **nvarchar**

I am using JPA repository to call the Stored Procedure

```
@Repository
public interface CustomRepo extends JpaRepository<ArchEntity, Long> {

   @Query(value = "{call dbo.storedproc(:objectType)}", nativeQuery = true)
   public List<Object> getData(@Param("objectType") String type);

}
```

Properties

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.datasource.initialize=false
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver:**********
spring.datasource.username=*****
spring.datasource.password=*****
```

And exception is

```
2018-11-13 09:43:02 - Servlet.service() for servlet 
[dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request 
processing failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC 
type: -9; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect 
mapping for JDBC type: -9] with root cause
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9
at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:70)
at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:101)
at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:666)
at
```

Comment: nvarchar should just be a java String, this seems like you are missing the right JPA settings in properties file. Can you update the question with datasource and jpa

Comment: Updated with properties @ChirdeepTomar